# React Final Form Material UI creating double lines on input field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-final-form

I have a strange thing happening where I can't really figure out what is creating those double input field lines in my code (see the picture). I have literally copied the code from the official website ([React Final Form](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-material-ui-example-tqv09?file=/src/index.jsx:0-5359)) and it doesn't seem to be happening there. Does it have something to do with the browser compatibility?

[image]

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-final-form';
import {
  TextField,
  Select,
} from 'mui-rff';
import {
  Grid,
  Button,
  MenuItem,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#008080',
    },
  }
}) 

const onSubmit = async values => {
  const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  await sleep(300);
  window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2));
};

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.firstName) {
    errors.firstName = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.lastName) {
    errors.lastName = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Required';
  }
  return errors;
};

const formFields = [
  {
    size: 6,
    field: (
      <TextField
        label="First Name"
        name="firstName"
        margin="none"
        required={true}
      />
    ),
  },
  {
    size: 6,
    field: (
      <TextField
        label="Last Name"
        name="lastName"
        margin="none"
        required={true}
      />
    ),
  },
  {
    size: 12,
    field: (
      <TextField
        type="email"
        label="Email"
        name="email"
        margin="none"
        required={true}
      />
    ),
  },
  {
    size: 12,
    field: <TextField name="notes" multiline label="Notes" margin="none" />,
  },
  {
    size: 12,
    field: (
      <Select
        name="city"
        label="Select a City"
        formControlProps={{ margin: 'none' }}
      >
        <MenuItem value="London">London</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="New York">New York</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="Tallinn">Tallinn</MenuItem>
      </Select>
  )
}
];

const FinalForm = () => {
    return (
         <div className="col s12 m6">
          <div className="card-panel grey lighten-3">
            <h5>Please fill out this form</h5>
        <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        validate={validate}
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
              <Grid container alignItems="flex-start" spacing={2}>
                {formFields.map((item, idx) => (
                  <Grid item xs={item.size} key={idx}>
                    {item.field}
                  </Grid>
                ))}
                <Grid item style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
                  <Button
                    type="button"
                    variant="contained"
                    onClick={form.reset}
                    disabled={submitting || pristine}
                  >
                    Reset
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    type="submit"
                    color='primary'
                    disabled={submitting}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                  </ThemeProvider>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
          </form>
          )}
          />
        </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default FinalForm;
```

Comment: do hard reload(Ctrl+F5) project tab in the browser. In my machine, there is no issue.

Comment: @MasudMorshed interesting. I am still getting it but I will have a look on my other computer later on today....Thanks for your help!